# LO Calc / Excel - Dropbox change another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, libreoffice-calc

I am creating a simple Point of Sale System for a store using an excel/libre office spreadsheet.

The spreadsheet has a sheet called "Inventory" which has the following columns:

1. Name
2. Price

This holds data like:

- Scrabble - $5
- Monopoly - $10
- Drink - $1
- Ice-cream - $2
- (etc, about 500 entries total)

It has another sheet called "Product Sales", which has two columns:

1. Item
2. Price

The first column "Item" uses cell validation to create a dropdown box that lets me choose from all of the names defined in "Inventory" (column 1).

I would like for "Product Sales".Price to automatically update to the appropriate Inventory.Price when "Product Sales".Item is changed.

The only way I can think to do this right now is with a huge, unwieldy, hard to edit, and bug-prone if statement.  Another way to do it would be with a for() loop, but I can't do that.

Is there some other method I'm not aware of?

Comment: Once you have selected the item, couldn't you do a vlookup on the inventory list?

Comment: Do you want a drop-down like data validation? Where the cell value can **only** be on the first list?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the user fixer1234, the appropriate function is vlookup"

```
 =IF( ISBLANK(B6), "", VLOOKUP(B6, Products.A3:D106, 4, 1) )
```

I had to move the column-to-match to column A, not sure if there's a workaround for that or not.  It wasn't a big problem for me.